# Laravel override username to another column does not work

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

So i am making a project in laravel 5.3 and I stumbled across an error while trying to modify my login.

As the title says, I am trying to login using different column instead of 'email', because i would like to have 3 emails for each user. So at first I would like to only change where the username is being get from. I did the following already.

I edited the `config/auth.php` file to listen to another model as this:

```
'providers' => [
   'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Guest::class,
   ]
]
```

and also in my `LoginController.php` file, I override the function username with this:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'email1';
}
```

This does not give me any error, but it wont redirect if I try to login with the credentials I have in my database. Anyone know a quick answer? Thankyou!

EDIT:

here is the schema of my guest table:

```
Schema::create('guests', function(Blueprint $table){

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('hash')->nullable();
        $table->string('password', 60)->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->string('ip')->nullable();

        $table->integer('reunion_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('middle_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('nickname')->nullable();
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('initials')->nullable();
        $table->string('sex')->nullable();
        $table->date('birthdate')->nullable();
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('postcode')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('location')->nullable();
        $table->string('country')->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile1')->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile2')->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile3')->nullable();
        $table->string('phone1')->nullable();
        $table->string('phone2')->nullable();
        $table->string('phone3')->nullable();
        $table->string('email1')->nullable()->unique();
        $table->string('email2')->nullable();
        $table->string('email3')->nullable();
        $table->integer('graduation')->nullable();
        $table->string('level')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('deceased')->nullable();
        $table->text('comment')->nullable();
        $table->string('linkedin')->nullable();
        $table->string('facebook')->nullable();
        $table->string('twitter')->nullable();
        $table->string('instagram')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('found')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('claimed')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('ticket')->default(false);

        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

I realize that the table name is guests and the model guest, but trust me they are connected

Comment: what's happening when you're trying to login? What's in `Guest` model?

Comment: @GiuServ please look at the edit file, there isn't happening anything. It just refreshes the page for some reason, it wont redirect to wrong or right..

Comment: ok @Hoffie, but is Guest extending `Authenticatable` class?

Comment: @GiuServ Yes it is!

Comment: But are you trying to login using a non unique field? You should use something unique, like `nickname` or something else if you don't want use email...

Comment: made it unique, good notice. But that wasn't the solution

Comment: @GiuServ maybe it helps to say that there are prefilled quests, but without the credentials of email and password. After they register, their fields will get filled in and then they would be able to log in.

Comment: Well, I've changed my credential columns too, but for me it was enough to adapt the `username` function.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by overriding the login method in the `LoginController` with the following snippet. I know it is not really a good practice, but if anyone knows a better way, please share it.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $email = $request->all()['email'];
    $password = $request->all()['password'];

    if (Auth::attempt(['email1' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Comment: You could also use `$request->input('email')`